# Can't install any software anymore on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I'm unable to install or remove any software package on Ubuntu. No matter how many times I try "apt-get -f install'.

```
--
jeroen@jeroen-panda:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 404 not upgraded.
38 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,794 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,571 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 104411 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad (from .../gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.7+1_armel.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.7+1_armel.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-0.10.so.0.0.0', which is also in package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good 0.10.30-1ubuntu7
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.7+1_armel.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
---
```

This is worse than Windows! One broken package, breaks your entire distro...

Comment: What exactly did you do to end up here? To my understanding `libgstcamerabin.so` isn't even supposed to be in that package.

Comment: "dpkg: error processing …_armel.deb" - This is an ARM architecture computer right?

Comment: Probably no point, but just try a reboot followed by 'sudo apt-get update' and then tru the installation.  Also, AskUbuntu.com may be more appropriate

Comment: Hi, yes this is an ARM pandaboard. I tried to install the "cheese" package, to get a webcam working. Anyway, no harm done if I need to reinstall it, so maybe that's just the easiest solution.

Comment: Did you tried to run an apt-get update and then an apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Check if that help: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/31667/no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-is-reached-already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your upgrading is stuck because of a stray package. Run this command in a terminal and see if that fixes your problem:

```
rm -rfv /usr/lib/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-0.10.so.0.0.0
```

I am just a little puzzled because [this bug was already fixed.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good0.10/+bug/828845)